# Magento2 on upgrade not generating static assets

Tags: magento2.2.6, magento-2.2.1

I made a copy of a website for upgrade from 2.2.1 to 2.2.6, but I think there is some small issue, which I am not able to figure out.

The static contents in the pub static folder are not getting generated, only the `requirejs-config.js`

When I my deploying static content with -f the assets are generated, but for the same file being there in the website I am getting a 404.

The `.htacess` file is there in the static folder.

Comment: I think you need to check if the .htaccess file is present in the static folder or not. If not then copy the .htaccess file from static folder of any other magento2 installation. It should work.

Comment: I have already mentioned in my comment that `.htaccess` file is present.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf var/generated
rm -rf pub/static
```

Then regenerate as you normally would

Answer (score 0):

1. change the deploy mode to developer. `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`
2. run  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`